# How to solve this integer equations?

Tags: problem-solving, integers

Conditions 
$$\begin{array}{ll}
   1. \quad&1\le i<j\le n\\
   2. &p=i\cdot n-n-\frac{i^2}2+j-\frac i2,  1 \le p\le\frac{n(n-1)}2
\end{array}$$

given $p$, is there a way to solve for $i, j$ which is always unique that satisfies the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose p is given to be a positive value, then i=1 and j=p+1 will always be a solution. If there exists any other solution (which will often exist), then there is no unique solution. So the answer should be no.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the condition $1\le p\le\frac{n(n-1)}2$

Comment: Isn't my answer right even then?

Comment: no, let n=3, p=3, and i=1, so j=p+1=4 can't be the solution bcoz j<=n.

Comment: Well, in the solution i=1 and j=p+1, the value of n does appear in the equation (as $in-n$ becomes zero); it exists only in the conditions and can be as high as required.